# Why is this bash for loop slow?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to this code:

```
for f in jobs/UPDTEST/apples* ; do
    nf=`echo $f | sed s:jobs\/::g`
    echo $nf | tr '_' ' '
done > jobs
```

There are 750 `apples*` type text files. But as I am only messing with the file name - I would have thought it should be quick - but take about 5 mins.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use === ls jobs/UPDTEST/apples* | sed -e 's:.*apples:apples:g;s/_/ /g' > jobs === ? Certainly the way you do it is far from efficient, at least because you use quite long argument list, and call "sed" and "tr" nth number of times, nested pipes and whatsoever else. You complicated it too much.

Comment: It's slow because `forks` for the pipes are expensive and you fork up to four processes per iteration. Forking just to change a few characters is like having your groceries delivered on a flatbed truck. Any shell programmer who wants to avoid forks must know the shell's builtin toolbox inside out.

Comment: @PiotrWadas Your suggestion works very well with slight changes: ls -d jobs/UPDTEST/apples* | sed -e 's:jobs\/::g;s/_/ /g' > jobs  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [parameter expansions](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) like `${parameter/pattern/string}` to get rid of the calls to `sed` and `tr`. In your case it could look like:

```
for f in jobs/UPDTEST/apples*; do
    f=${f//jobs\//}
    echo ${f//_/ }
done > jobs
```

Comment: There are various good answers here. So I am choosing this as I am likely to use it OR PiotrWadas version in comments

Answer (score 1):

First, `cd jobs` would remove the need for the `sed`

Second, you don't need `tr` to substitute characters in the value of a bash variable.

Third, with `find` you don't need a loop at all.

```
f=$(cd jobs; find UPDTEST -name 'apples*' -depth 1)
echo "${f//_/ }" > jobs.log
```

By the way, you can't have a `jobs` directory and a `jobs` file in the same directory.

Comment: With `f=$(cd jobs; find ...)` you can even save the `cd ..`.

Comment: @Jens - You are correct! I edit my answer to  include your comment.